# Git with Smart HTTP Transport. Is git update-server-info needed?

Tags: apache-2.2, http, git

I am setting up a Git server using HTTP transport. As both my server and the clients will be using Git >= 1.6.6, [Smart HTTP Transport](http://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/04/smart-http.html) is enabled.

The Git manual section about [the HTTP/S Protocol](http://git-scm.com/book/ch4-1.html#The-HTTP/S-Protocol) says that I need to enable a `post-update` hook calling:

```
git update-server-info
```

Is this command still needed when using the Smart HTTP Transport (Git >= 1.6.6)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have set up the `git-http-backend` on the server correctly: No.

Personally I would leave the `update-server-info` hook in place. Doesn't hurt (not enough to matter, anyway).

Comment: Thanks! Leaving the hook in place is not an issue. I just wanted to know how hard I should remember to enable the hook on each newly-created repository.